# R Shiny Data Table Highlight Row Based on SelectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which outputs a data table. I would like the row in the data table corresponding to the `selectInput` picker to be highlighted green (i.e. when 'C' is selected, that entire row would be colored green - same for the other options). Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

```
library(shiny)

dat <- data.frame(grp = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  val = 1:3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("grp", "Select Group", choices = c("A", "B", "C")),
  dataTableOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tab <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(dat)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `formatStyle` with reactive values in setting row `backgroundColor` with `styleEqual()` [[docs](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)]:

```r
library(shiny)

grp_list <- c("A", "B", "C")
dat <- data.frame(grp = grp_list,
                  val = 1:3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("grp", "Select Group", choices = grp_list),
  dataTableOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals <- reactiveValues(
    row_priority = grp_list,
    row_color = rep('white', 3)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$grp, {
    vals$row_priority <- 
      c(input$grp, vals$row_priority[vals$row_priority != input$grp])
    vals$row_color <- c('lightgreen', 'white', 'white')
  })
  
  output$tab <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(dat) %>% 
      formatStyle("grp",
                  target = "row",
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual(vals$row_priority, 
                                               vals$row_color, 
                                               default = 'white')
      )
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]